# Cómo utilizo la dirección url del navegador en un botón del formulario

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

Estoy creando mi archivo `buscar.php`. A la hora de realizar la búsqueda, estoy reescribiendo la url:

```
localhost/tienda/buscar/lapicero/
```

A:

```
localhost/tienda/buscar.php?q=lapicero
```

Con el .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^buscar/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$ buscar.php?q=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

lo cual he conseguido sólo cuando escribo la URL.

Pero mi gran duda es cómo hago para que el botón del formulario haga la solicitud a la URL de arriba, la que está en la barra de direcciones, y no utilice esto:

```
localhost/tienda/buscar/?q=goma
```

Me interesa eliminar el parámetro `"?q="` que se genera.

Mi resultado deseado sería algo así al presiona el botón buscar:

```
localhost/tienda/buscar/goma/
```

PD: este es mi codigo html del formulario

```
<form action="<?php echo $url; ?>/buscar/" method="GET" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="buscador" name="q" id="q" size="60">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Lee sobre patrón MVC; para PHP hay varios FrameWorks para ello entre muchos (sin orden alguno de interes): Doctrine, CakePHP entre otros más. Te dara como resultado o que buscas.

Comment: @Mariano hola, error mio al publicar el post, pero ya lo corregi

Comment: Puedes poner el código que tienes en buscar.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta esto:

```
<button onclick="buscar()">Buscar</button>
<script>
    function buscar() {
          window.open("localhost/buscacosas/buscar/" + document.getElementById("txtbuscar").value, "_parent");
    } 
</script>
```

En la paginas que quieres que te realice la funcion

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta pero no logre conseguirlo solo funciona para la primera busqueda para la segunda busqueda acumula URL, y tambien ya no puedo usar el ENTER tengo que hacer click al boton para buscar

Comment: Podrias decir a que te refieres con "acumular URL", ademas para que te busque pulsando ENTER solo tines que agregar al input un evento onkeypress donde verificas si el valor presionado es equivalente a ENTER en el codigo ASCII y llamas a tu funcion buscar

Comment: hola a lo que escribi que se acumula URL me habia equivocado ya esta solucionado ahora probe tu codigo y funciona casi perfecto pero me falta agregarle un "/" al final de tu codigo, como lo haria ?? ---> localhost/buscacosas/buscar/" + document.getElementById("txtbuscar")+"/".value  ASI SERIA ???

Comment: ya lo solucione lo del "/" solo me falta el ENTER al buscar

Comment: Agrega este script:

function verificar(event) {
      var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
      if(x==13){
       window.open("localhost/buscacosas/buscar/" + document.getElementById("txtbuscar").value, "_parent");
      }
     }

Ademas de agregar este atributo a tu input
onkeypress="verificar(event)"

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta tambien me es efectiva

Answer (score 1):

crea en raiz un archivo llamada **.htaccess**, si ya existe solo agrégale lo que sigue:

```
# enable rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# if requested url does not exist pass it as path info to index.php
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?/ [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar todo desde el .htaccess, hay que tener en cuenta 2 casos:

1. Si tiene un parámetro de búsqueda como `buscar/?q=[búsqueda]&más=parámetros`

   - Eliminar ese parámetro de la lista de parámetros (dejar el resto).
   - **Redireccionar** a `buscar/[búsqueda]/?más=parámetros`.

     ---
2. Si se accede a `buscar/[parámetro]/?más=parámetros`,

   - cuando **no** tiene un parámetro de búsqueda `?q=[búsqueda]`
   - **Reescribir** a `buscar.php?q=[búsqueda]&más=parámetros`.

---

### Código en el .htaccess

```python
RewriteEngine on

#Redireccionar parámetro de búsqueda a formato pretty URL
# - Toma ?q=valor y lo lleva a la url /buscar/valor/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(?:^|&)q=([^&]*)(.*)
RewriteCond %2/&%1%3 ^([^&]+?/)?/*&+(.*)
RewriteRule ^buscar(?:/|$) buscar/%1?%2 [R,NC,NE]

#Reescribir pretty URL para convertir en parámetro de búsqueda
# - Sólo cuando no tiene el parámetro de búsqueda &q=
# - Deja la URL /buscar/valor/ actual, pero accede a buscar.php?q=valor
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)q=
RewriteRule ^buscar(?:/([^/]+))?/?$ buscar.php?q=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

**Ejemplos**

```python
+-----------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------------+
|                URL                |      Redirección       |         Reescritura        |
+-----------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------------+
| /buscar                           | -                      | /buscar.php?q=             |
| /buscar/                          | -                      | /buscar.php?q=             |
| /buscar?q=q                       | /buscar/q/             | /buscar.php?q=q            |
| /buscar/?q=q                      | /buscar/q/             | /buscar.php?q=q            |
| /buscar/?a=b&q=q                  | /buscar/q/?a=b         | /buscar.php?q=q&a=b        |
| /buscar/?q=z&d=e                  | /buscar/z/?d=e         | /buscar.php?q=z&d=e        |
| /buscar/anterior/?x=y&q=nueva&z=w | /buscar/nueva/?x=y&z=w | /buscar.php?q=nueva&x=y&z=w|
+-----------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------------+
```

**Demo**

Subí el ejemplo a un hosting gratuito:
[http://mariano.uphero.com/61816/buscar?a=123&q=búsqueda&más=parámetros](http://mariano.uphero.com/61816/buscar?a=123&q=b%C3%BAsqueda&m%C3%A1s=par%C3%A1metros)

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta y tu ejemplo !! funciona perfecto saludos !!